Elongation of a spring
Here are two springs,both initially at their relaxed length. But,the 2nd one is connected with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$. I pull on both the springs on both sides with a constant force $F$. What will be the maximum elongation for each of them?

Note : Both their spring constant is $k$.

As this isn't a "do my homework" site, what exactly is it that you have difficulties with? What have you tried? What do you understand and what not (or at least think so)?

For the 1st one,I think it is similar to a spring which has its one end attached with a wall.So,at equilibrium, x=F/k.so x_max=2F/k.Not really sure about the 2nd one.

Is the question about the equilibrium or about the dynamics before reaching the equilibrium?

It just asks the maximum elongation

In "x_max=2F/k", why do you use the factor of 2 in this case but not in the "wall" case? (Hint: does the wall not apply a force to the spring?) Or do I misunderstand your reasoning?

My reasoning:The 1st case is similar to a horizontal spring which has one end attached with a wall.If I pull with a force F,the wall will also pull with a force F.But as it is attached,the fixed end will not move.Using energy conservation,Fx=1/2kx² (x is the maximum elongation)so x=2F/k

The OP's comments make clear that this question is not about the equilibrium that will eventually be reached after some oscillation has decayed to zero, but about the oscillation phase.
The OP also commented about conservation of energy, so we will follow that (very plausible) approach.
We make the assumption that there is no loss of energy due to friction effects or similar, so the oscillation continues forever.
To the whole system ($m_1$, spring, $m_2$), two forces with the same value $F$ and opposite direction are applied, so the center of gravity of the system will not accelerate, but stay in place.
During the oscillation, when $m_1$ comes to a momentary halt at its leftmost point, $m_2$ must also have velocity zero (otherwise the center of gravity would move, which it doesn't - see above). So, we identified the situation of maximum elongation.
In this situation, the energy in the system is in the elongated spring, there is no kinetic energy as both masses are at halt. We have two parts of the spring elongation: $x_{1,max}$ to the left and $x_{2,max}$ to the right.
Now, you can compute the work done by the left and the right force along their parts of the elongation, using $x_{1,max}$ and $x_{2,max}$, and you can compute the energy stored in the elongated spring, using the total elongation $x_{1,max} + x_{2,max}$.
The sum of the works by the two forces must equal the resulting energy in the spring, and you can solve that equality to give you the maximum elongation, being $x_{1,max} + x_{2,max}$.
You'll find out that the distribution of the elongation to the left and the right part does not matter.
